# Sharing strings across classes

Tags: c#, wpf, class, mvvm, enumeration

I have a combobox that lists hard drives, binded to that for selected value is a string called currentdrive which when selected value on the box changes, enumerates selected hard drive, filling a listbox with image files, but I have a second listbox that needs to also know the current hard drive, this listbox won't be displaying images, I intend it to display metadata about the images but I need this box to know what the selected harddrive is before it can display metadata. Because metadata etc will be in its own class how can I access the currentdrive string without, repeating the currentdrive string, I want the metadata class to be able to share that functionality.

Comment: Please try to show code (5-10 lines related to the question). It is not yet clear why you must "share" string across classes - if there is no particular reason each class may have own copy of a string (also this comment based on title, body of the post is less clear)... Note: there is no need for any kind of "thank you notes", "new here", "help me" text in the post.

Comment: I'm sorry if you take my edit as insult. If you feel that my edits removed important information from the post - you can easily revert the changes. If you disagree with my removal of your thank you - feel free to discuss on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions), but check previous discussions on [it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) first. I don't think I've looked at any of your previous questions, sorry - I'm bad with names. If I ever fixed spelling mistakes is only because browser's spell-checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you have what is in essence, a second ViewModel, and you want to access data from the original ViewModel, the solution to that is what's called a Singleton Pattern, and is used in this fashion:

```
public class ViewModel()
{
    public static ViewModel Instance;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public string foo = "bar";
}
```

In your second class:

```
public class DifferentViewModel()
{
    public DifferentViewModel()
    {
        this.bar = ViewModel.Instance.foo;
    }

    public string bar;
}
```

Comment: except foo/bar must be public

Comment: I shall give this a try, much appreciated